# XCTest and asynchronous testing in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

So Apple said in the release note of Xcode 6 that we can now do asynchronous testing directly with XCTest.

Anyone knows how to do it using Xcode 6 Beta 3 (Using objective-C or Swift)? I don't want the known semaphore method, but the new Apple way.

I searched into the released note and more but I found nothing. The XCTest header is not very explicit either.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The sessions video is perfect, basically you want to do something like this

```
func testFetchNews() {
    let expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("fetch posts")

    Post.fetch(.Top, completion: {(posts: [Post]!, error: Fetcher.ResponseError!) in
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
        expectation.fulfill()
    })

    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 68):

Obj-C example:

```
- (void)testAsyncMethod
{

    //Expectation
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Testing Async Method Works!"];

    [MyClass asyncMethodWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse, NSData *data) {

        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error is: %@", error);
        }else{
            NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
            XCTAssertEqual(statusCode, 200);
            [expectation fulfill];
        }

    }];


    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {

        if(error)
        {
            XCTFail(@"Expectation Failed with error: %@", error);
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: silly question: what if my `asyncMethod` doesn´t have a completion block? I have no idea how to test this.

Comment: Assuming you run it on a dispatch_queue, you can schedule your test on the same queue after you started the work you were planning on doing. Just dispatch_async onto the same queue and then in that continuation block do what you need to

Answer (score 11):

Session 414 covers async testing in Xcode6

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#414

Comment: To make it easier to find in the list: this session is named "Testing in Xcode 6".

Answer (score 1):

How I did in swift2

Step 1: define expectation

```
let expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("get result bla bla")
```

Step 2: tell the test to fulfill expectation right below where you capture response

```
responseThatIGotFromAsyncRequest = response.result.value
expectation.fulfill()
```

Step 3: Tell the test to wait till the expectation is fulfilled

```
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10)
```

STep 4: make assertion after async call is finished

```
XCTAssertEqual(responseThatIGotFromAsyncRequest, expectedResponse)
```