# How do I support/add a completion handler to my asynchronous method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, completion

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704338/xctest-and-asynchronous-testing-in-xcode-6/25925193#25925193) to test an asynchronous method I defined in a class. However I am unable to add a completion handler defintion to it. Any help?

I got a method defined as following:

```
//.h
- (void)loadData;

//.m   
 - (void)loadData{
        NSString *urlString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.example.com/json", kResultsLimit ];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           }
    }];
```

I would like now to add a completion handler to the loadData method definition.. how can I add it both in the .h and .m file?

example of .h:

```
        - (void)loadData+completionhandler;
```

Comment: Just add it. What's the question?

Comment: @matt I have really no idea how to add it in the .h and .m file.. especially the .m file.. do I need to write some code for it?

Comment: I repeat: what's the problem? A completion handler is a block, exactly as in the code you have already shown. What don't you know how to do?

Comment: You can just type it like the code you had posted. What's the issue?

Comment: There are many methods like what you want in iOS. Find it before asking. Exp: `+ [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AdamPro13 gives you an example of how to do it.

My guess is that you're struggling with how to define a method that takes a block as a parameter. It's confusing.

I use this site (with a less SFW URL name) to figure out the syntax of using blocks in different situations:

[GoshDarnLinkSyntax](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/)

The key bit for you is this part:

Passing a block as a method parameter:

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^)(parameterTypes))blockName;
```

Comment: That's great. I am trying this out.. however I need to find some reference on how to invoke "blockName" inside the completion handler of the block defined in the function above.

Comment: To call a block you use the same syntax as you use to invoke a function: `blockName(parameters)`, or just `blockName()` if it doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it in your `.h` like so: `- (void)loadDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(id))completion;`.

You can then call it in the completion handler of that network request with `completion(data);`